# Are lots of media queries spread across files ok

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using stylus for css and I like to try and contain smaller more manageable  snippets/modules of styles across lots of files/dirs.

Is it ok to have media queries in each of these files, so the query is only relevant to the styles in the same styl/css file? Would this cause any sort of performance issues (other than my css file being larger due to multiple query statements)?

eg

```
//a.sty

#a ...

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px)

  #a ...


@media only screen and (min-width: 900px)

  #a ...
```

...

```
//b.sty

#b ...

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px)

  #b ...


@media only screen and (min-width: 900px)

  #b ...
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/unique-pages-unique-css-files/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First question:

> Is it ok to have media queries in each of these files, so the query is only relevant to the styles in the same styl/css file?

Yes, I have seen a lot of long responsive.styl files, and they are not pretty. It is best to separate media queries into the files they belong in.

One word of caution. Keep your media query values in one file (e.g. `variables.styl`) or you will soon regret it when you want to change them later.

To implement this in Stylus I do the following:

In `variables.styl`

```
    smartphoneWidth = 748px
    tabletWidth     = 1012px

    mqSmartphone = "only screen and (max-width: " + smartphoneWidth + ")"
    mqTablet     = "only screen and (max-width: " + tabletWidth     + ")"
```

Now in your other stylus files you can use:

```
    @media mqSmartphone
        // Styles go here

    @media mqTablet
        // Styles go here
```

#### Second question:

> Would this cause any sort of performance issues (other than my css file being larger due to multiple query statements)?

The multiple queries shouldn't affect the css parsing efficiency by any noticeable amount.
See [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/13/coding-qa-with-chris-coyier-responsive-sprites-responsive-font-sizing-media-query-efficiency-more/) for confirmation.