# putting media query in a mixin

Tags: css, media-queries, stylus

I have many css files and many occurrences of:

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px), (orientation: portrait) {
    ....//In each file different style that relevant to the component the file represnt
}
```

I am using stylus.
One day my boss asked me to change that media query to:

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px), (max-height: 400px) {
    ....
}
```

Now I need to search all my files and replace to the new media query.

Is there any option to put this media query in a mixin or something?

Comment: You can if you're using SASS.

Comment: @Tyriar: How in SASS?

Comment: made an answer with the SASS method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from a [question I answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222219/are-lots-of-media-queries-spread-across-files-ok/17231406#17231406). Here is the hack I use:

In `variables.styl`

```
smartphoneWidth = 748px
tabletWidth     = 1012px

mqSmartphone = "only screen and (max-width: " + smartphoneWidth + ")"
mqTablet     = "only screen and (max-width: " + tabletWidth     + ")"
```

Now in your other stylus files you can use:

```
@media mqSmartphone
    // Styles go here

@media mqTablet
    // Styles go here
```

While still ugly, I feel it is slightly more elegant than using unquote()

Answer (score 11):

With stylus, you can also define a couple of [block mixins](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/mixins.html#block-mixins) if you prefer. I use this:

```
widerthan(var)
  condition = 'screen and (min-width: %s)' % var
  @media condition
    {block}

narrowerthan(var)
  condition = 'screen and (max-width: %s)' % var
  @media condition
    {block}

mobile = 748px
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
button
  +narrowerthan(mobile)
    flex-direction column
```

Comment: Though the selected answer is an option, and works great, this answer actually answers the question, and is more elegant IMHO. The selected answer doesn't use mixins and is a self-proclaimed "hack".

Answer (score 0):

As Stylus don't support interpolation or variables in media queries (or block arguments for mixins), you could only use this hack:

```
$my_query = "@media all and (max-width: 400px), (orientation: portrait) {"

unquote($my_query)
…
unquote("}")
```

then when you'll need to change the query, you would need to change the `$mu_query` variable.

The only drawback aside from ugly syntax is that this won't work for bubbled mediaqueries.